# actionSupport doesn't work with image component?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

SFDC shall display a refresh icon on Page & it should refresh.

page:

```
<apex:image  url="{!$Resource.ECOB_Refresh}" width="25" height="25">
   <apex:actionSupport event="onClick" action="{!refresh}" reRender="fileTable"/>
</apex:image>
```

It appears that if I put an actionSupport component within a image componenet it doesn't work.
How to achieve this scenario,is there any alternative.

Comment: Can you please post some of the code snippet you have tried so far.

Comment: Just checking, is your `apex:image` contained within `apex:form`? I had this problem once when the image was not within an apex:form and it worked once I corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<apex:form>
  <apex:commandlink action="{!refresh}" reRender="fileTable">
    <apex:image  url="{!$Resource.ECOB_Refresh}" width="25" height="25"></apex:image>
  </apex:commandlink>
</apex:form>
```